# "No suitable application records were found" when uploading Xcode Archive

Tags: ios, cocoapods

When submitting an archive to the App Store I receive the following error:

> No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'org.cocoapods.grpcpp' is correct.

I've already double checked that my bundle identifier is correctly set in my project's target (same as in App Store Connect).

Reinstalling Cocoapods did not help either.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4zd2.png

Comment: is iPhone app target is selected?

Comment: The app archives perfectly fine, it's just when I attempt to distribute it to the App Store that I get this error.

Comment: is your iPhone app's b bundle identifier is `org.cocoapods.grpcpp`?

Comment: No, it's not. That identifier is coming from an included pod framework.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, iTunes Connect (http://itunesconnect.apple.com) is the receiver of your App bundle when you use the Xcode Uploader utility (in Observer). So unless you have an App with the same bundle identifier created in the iTunes Connect web dashboard, you'll never be able to upload a build. Creating an App on the dashboard is easy, follow these steps from the iTunes home screen:

Create new app if not exist already and submit all required information. or Click the app in question. Click More -> Then About This App Then change the Bundle ID to the one you created in the provisioning portal.

Comment: Like mentioned before, the bundle identifier already matches the identifier I have set on the App Store Connect. For some reason it is just taking the bundle id of one of the pod dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by:

- Creating an entirely new Xcode project
- Copying my podfile across and installing pods to this new project
- Copying practically the entire contents of my previous Xcode project across, including the info.plist

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you need to create the app in your App Connect first to make it know where to store the uploaded app.

Answer (score 0):

If you created app in iTunes connect and still facing this issue then check for Xcode(>11.0) File-> Workspace Setting -> Build System - **Legacy Build System.** Also you can check with adding apple account again in Xcode.